# Grammatically analyze "Why drivers were left stranded"

Tags: grammar, parts-of-speech

Grammatically analyze below

> Why drivers were left stranded.

"Why" is the interrogative, but not sure if it is describing drivers.
"Were left" is the verb, but not sure the grammatical role of left.
And "stranded" is the adjective describing drivers.

Comment: If it's a *question*, it's ***Why were** drivers left stranded?* Alternatively, it could feature a fairly old-fashioned initial exclamation - ***Why**! Drivers were left stranded!* With the speaker expressing surprise *(**Why = Golly gosh**!)* at the fact that drivers were stranded, with no assistance forthcoming.

Comment: @FumbleFingers It's simply an embedded-question noun phrase like you'd use for a title, or for the complement of "I know know X".

Answer (score 1):

> Why drivers were left stranded.

is not a grammatical sentence. If that's the precise word order, I would say it's part of a bigger sentence (perhaps, *Why drivers were left stranded is beyond me.*), in which case *Why drivers were left stranded* functions as an *embedded interrogative clause* (no *S-V inversion*, as a result). If, however, it's to be considered a complete sentence in its own right, you've to recast it as: *Why were the drivers left stranded?* {*S-V inversion* mandated in this case.}

Comment: She never said it was a sentence.